# Perl - Can large exponent cause error: Argument "XXX" isn't numeric in printf

Tags: perl

A Perl script being run on OpenSuse 42.3 is giving the error: Argument "1.000+136" isn't numeric in printf . The script reads through many exponentially formmatted numbers and writes them to a new file. This is the only number that the script complains about in a file with hundreds of numbers. The file has the following format:

```
23. OH+HO2=H2O+O2                                                                                                                                                                        
         2.510E+12    2.000    40000.000
      Declared duplicate reaction...
24. OH+HO2=H2O+O2                                                                                                                                                                        
         1.000+136  -40.000    34800.000
      Declared duplicate reaction...
25. H2O2+H=HO2+H2                                                                                                                                                                        
         6.050E+06    2.000     5200.000
```

The print statement used to print to a file is:

```
printf Outfile "\{ a = %.3E n = %5.3f E = %7.3f ",$kA[$ireac],$kb[$ireac],$kE[$ireac];
```

Is it that the number has an exponent of 136 that may cause an issue? Is there a way to resolve an issue like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string will be automatically numified in this situation, but only if its value would be a valid Perl [numeric literal](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values).

`1.000+136` should be `1.000E+136` (`E` was left out) or `1.000E136` (`+` was used insead of `E`).

Comment: I'm unable to see where your answer is going. Is there a solution to this issue? Is "1.000+136" a number that Perl can write with formatted output?

Comment: Re "*Is there a solution to this issue*", As I mentioned, you should be using `1.000E136` or `1.000E+136` instead of `1.000+136`.

Comment: Re "*Is "1.000+136" a number that Perl can write with formatted output?*", Of course. Perl is a general purpose programming language.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you for the clarification. My eyes glossed over the fact that the "E' was missing from this number. I guess I'll have to dig deeper to find out why the code that wrote that number decided to remove the E just for that particular number.